# REST Web Service xml parameters order

Tags: java, rest, web-services

In the RESTful web service is the order of parameters are important or they can be at any order ?

Comment: Order should not matter as the parameters are passed as name-value pairs through the Http headers

Comment: It will be placed inside a `Map`, so it doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but the parameters are not placed inside header. They are placed in xml format in body.

Comment: What "parameters" are you referring to?

Answer (score 1):

If they are `Path` parameters, the order will matter, e.g.

```
https://your.api/order/#{orderNumber}/#{responseType}/
```

needs to be:

```
https://your.api/order/1234/json/
```

if the body is composed of name=value pairs, the order doesn't matter, e.g.

```
responseType=json
orderNumber=1234
```

if the body contains an `XML` payload the order MAY matter. e.g.

```
<request>
  <responseType>json</responseType>
  <orderNumber>1234</orderNumber>
</request>
```

MAY work fine depending how the server processes the `XML` payload. If the server validates the `XML` payload using an `XMLSchema` file (`XSD`) then the order will matter and must match the order in which the elements are declared in the `XSD`.